# J.Doe should be able to localize

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization

On the [registration page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup) (open in private mode) *Display Name* field's placeholder (`J. Doe`) doesn't exist in transifex, i.e. impossible to localize it.

> [image: J.Doe]

Another string with *"John Doe"* [already translated in transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264454?key=15b1e5eae38b3241b249b6718c3f559a).

Comment: There is also a raw "Email" there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "Email" is in transifex, but in [full sentence](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267108?key=b611e2db9643c95e35b3f72ea0474c51) this word translated as is. I'm not sure that we need to translate it. But we can.

Comment: Yeah, think you better translate the single word too, it looks weird being the only word in English.

Comment: Wouldn't a name also be the same in all languages? E.g. what would you localize J. Doe into? They're not English words, that's a first initial, last name combination often used to signify an unknown identity.

Comment: @animuson Presumably a linguistically-appropriate placeholder name. Don't think of "J. Doe" as a name, because it isn't - it's a "your name goes here" indicator. That may not make sense in other languages.

Comment: @animuson we already have one [option](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4783/176217).

Comment: Think it's better to use the existing translation for "John Doe" then, it's the same thing anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizard existing string contains not only "John Doe". It's "John Doe$br$United States". I showed it here, because I think you don't have access to transifex.

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't really fit. I can see the project itself, but not the strings.

Comment: @animuson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language

Comment: @m0sa that list lacks an entry for "Joe Blow" and that irks me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you [Doe](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/108247726?key=fd2fe8600e216adb3862d722337bf049)